# how does shared view application works?

Tags: protocols, shared, multiplayer, multi-user

I am just curious to know how does shared view application works.
Application, lets say general term like web-app, online games etc.

I would like to know which protocol they use or framework/api they use in shared view application

examples say,

1. there are two users logged in and they share same data. And one of them changes data then how other user will know there is change in data and its view auto matically re-freshed?
2. On-line game, if two useres are playing multi-player game then how there view gets updated if either user changes some data.

**how this works and which protocol/framework they follow?**

Any reference `sites`/`blogs` and

If example in `framework`/`protocol` example in `java`/`spring` would be great

Comment: I guess this is not the view that update the data, user1 send data update to the server, then server send data to all players that need it and all views update.

Comment: Yes, its not view. But what protocol it follow?

Comment: If you mean communication protocol, it depends on the platform, webapps/javascript can use websocket to do "real time" / bidirectional communication, else (not web based) you can use pure socket and make you own "protocol"